# Failing to save objects to db with @GeneratedValue(IDENTITY) and bidirectional @OneToMany

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am having troubles persisting and cascading two entities, both with generated ids.

Database tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CISLO](
    [ID_CISLA] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        constraint PK_CISLO primary key (ID_CISLA)
        ...omit other columns for brevity
```

This table behaves just like binding one - it connects numbers to stack

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VAZBA_ZASOBNIK_CISLO](
    [ID_VAZBY_ZASOBNIK_CISLO] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_ZASOBNIKU] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID_CISLA] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        constraint PK_VAZBA_ZASOBNIK_CISLO primary key (ID_VAZBY_ZASOBNIK_CISLO)
    ...omit other columns for brevity

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZASOBNIK](
    [ID_ZASOBNIKU] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        constraint PK_ZASOBNIK primary key (ID_ZASOBNIKU)
        ...omit other columns for brevity
```

Entities looks like this

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)

@Entity
public class Cislo extends AbstractBaseEntity<Cislo, Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCisla;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cislo", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Collection<VazbaZasobnikCislo> numberStackRelations = new LinkedList<>();

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Entity
public class VazbaZasobnikCislo extends AbstractBaseEntity<VazbaZasobnikCislo, Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idVazbyZasobnikCislo;

    @NotNull
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ZASOBNIKU")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Zasobnik zasobnik;

    @NotNull
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CISLA")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Cislo cislo;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)

@Entity
public class Zasobnik extends AbstractBaseEntity<Zasobnik, Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idZasobniku;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "zasobnik", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Collection<VazbaZasobnikCislo> numberStackRelations = new LinkedList<>();
```

Now the program part

I am trying to create number (Cislo) and link it to existing stack (Zasobnik) by creating number-stack relation (VazbaZasobnikCislo).Entire block runs in transaction session using spring's @Transactional (with open-in-view disabled). "stack" variable is persistent entity Zasobnik. "asNew" just sets the flag isNew for Persistable interface (this time maybe unnecessary due to id generation).

```
var number = new Cislo(purpose, remainingRange.getFrom(), false, false, false);
var numberStackRelation = VazbaZasobnikCislo.initialize("CISRAD", stack, number.asNew());
vazbaZasobnikCisloService.save(numberStackRelation.asNew());
```

VazbaZasobnikCislo.initialize keeps other relations in sync.

```
private VazbaZasobnikCislo(String autorZmeny, Zasobnik zasobnik, Cislo cislo) {
    this.zasobnik = zasobnik;
    this.cislo = cislo;
    this.auditAttributes = new AuditAttributes(autorZmeny);
}

public static VazbaZasobnikCislo initialize(String autorZmeny, Zasobnik stack, Cislo number) {
    var stackNumberRelation = new VazbaZasobnikCislo(autorZmeny, stack, number);
    stack.getNumberStackRelations().add(stackNumberRelation);
    number.getNumberStackRelations().add(stackNumberRelation);
    return stackNumberRelation;
}
```

The following code produces this sql:

```
Hibernate:
    insert
    into
        CISLO
        (CERPANO_V_CILOVEM_SYSTEMU_AN, DATUM_ZARAZENI_BLACKLIST, DATUM_ZMENY, HODNOTA_CISLA, NEOPRAVNENE_POUZITI_AN, POUZITE_AN, ID_UCELU)
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) select
            scope_identity()
Hibernate:
    insert
    into
        VAZBA_ZASOBNIK_CISLO
        (AUTOR_ZMENY, DATUM_ZMENY, ID_CISLA, ID_UZIVATELE_KOMU_PRIDELENO, POPIS, ID_POZADAVKU, ID_UCTU_KOMU_PRIDELENO, ID_ZASOBNIKU)
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) select
            scope_identity()
2021-06-10 14:40:23.158  WARN 61377 --- [nio-8087-exec-6] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : SQL Error: 547, SQLState: 23000
2021-06-10 14:40:23.161 ERROR 61377 --- [nio-8087-exec-6] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : Příkaz INSERT způsobil konflikt s omezením FOREIGN KEY s názvem FK_VAZBA_ZA_R_VAZBA_C_CISLO. Ke konfliktu došlo v databázi CISRAD_KOOP, tabulce dbo.CISLO, , column 'ID_CISLA'.
```

`FK_VAZBA_ZA_R_VAZBA_C_CISLO` is defined like:

alter table VAZBA_ZASOBNIK_CISLO
add constraint FK_VAZBA_ZA_R_VAZBA_C_CISLO foreign key (ID_CISLA)
references CISLO (ID_CISLA)
on update cascade
go

If you need any more information, let me know. I am going to provide catched SQL profiler result what is actually being sent do the database.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a database instead of insert trigger.